# Magento 2.3: Add stock status filter in product admin grid

Tags: magento2, filter, stock-status

I want to add stock status dropdwon filter in product admin grid like this:
[image]

I tried this: https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-add-stock-status-column-in-admin-product-grid-magento-2/
but it didnt work.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? A bit more information would be helpful.

Comment: It is showing a few instock items as well when we search for out of stock items.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @mechanic Try this one I hope it works-

```
<column name="stock_status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Stock Status</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-stock-status-column-in-product-grid-in-magento-2/

Comment: I need to ass a "filter" not a column.

Comment: Hi @mechanic I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.